# SQL to convert EntryDate (column) to NULL if Country (column) is Gabon

Tags: sql, date

I am looking for SQL code to do the following correctly. I am struggling converting the existing date value to NULL in the case where the country is Gabon. Any help appreciated.

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN COUNTRY = 'GABON' 
        THEN ENTRYDATE IS NULL 
END AS ENTRYDATE

CASE 
    WHEN COUNTRY = 'GABON' 
        THEN ENTRYDATE IS NULL 
END AS ENTRYDATE
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format `CASE` `WHEN` condition properly.

```
CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'GABON' THEN  cast(null as Datetime) ELSE ENTRYDATE END AS ENTRYDATE
```

Note: Cast The data Type Based on `ENTRYDATE` Column

Comment: this worked too
convert(date,Entrydate, NULL)

Comment: `CAST` or  `CONVERT` gives you same result.